# align separate align environments in lyx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, align, amsmath, page-breaking

Suppose I have multiple `align` environments which consist of multiple lines of equations. How do I align the separate align environments to the `=` sign?

What I want to achieve:

```
first we do the multiplication (text)
a = 1x2 + 2x3 + 4 (mathmode)
  = 2+6+4 (mathmode)
now we perform the addition (text)
a = 8+4 (mathmode)
  = 12 (mathmode)
```

The above is of course a simplified example. What I want to do ultimately is to define a few large matrices. I want each matrix to be aligned to the `=` sign, to number each matrix individually, and if there isn't enough space it will continue to the next page (if I just one single `align` environment to contain all matrices then I find out if there isn't enough space remaining on a page if will just start the whole block on a new page, leaving lots of unwanted empty space on the original page).

So, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble allows for pagebreaks in `align`s. You can add text between lines of an `align` or `gather` using `\intertext`, but it seems there isn't real support for this in LyX: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/723

Comment: You could post this as an answer because it is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Now `amsmath` does have support for this kind of thing, it involves `\allowdisplaybreaks`/`\displaybreak` and `\intertext`, the former two for page breaks, the latter for text between lines of an `align`:

- Placing `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble will allow for page breaks in all multiline display math environments from `amsmath`.
- Adding `\displaybreak` before a specific `\\` in an `align` allows for a pagebreak after that specific line.
- `\intertext{text}` should be placed inside an `align` environment after a `\\`, and places `text` on a "normal" text line, continuing the alignment after it.

Hence, your simple example could be written in LaTeX as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
first we do the multiplication (text)
\begin{align}
a &= 1\times 2 + 2\times 3 + 4 \\
  &= 2+6+4 \\
\intertext{now we perform the addition}
a &= 8+4 \\
  &= 12 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

In LyX you're a bit worse off though, as `\intertext` isn't currently supported in the GUI, see feature request at http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/723. I can't think of any good workarounds at the moment, writing the whole `align`s in ERTs is probably not of interest for you.

But allowing for page breaks in all `align` environments is as you see easy, just go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add `\allowdisplaybreaks`.